# Unit testing: how do I know which private function has broken without unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

I've read, ad infinitum, stuff like:

*You shouldn't need to expose private methods to your tests. The public methods of your class have a specification. Your unit tests should be testing that the public methods of your class adhere to that specification. How the public methods go about doing that is no one's business; you want to be free to change your private implementation however you like as long as you continue to adhere to the specification of your public methods.*

So:

- **I have a public function, that calls various smaller private functions.**
- **The public function breaks.**
- **How do I know which private function has broken?**

Comment: @SLaks I already use a debugger - but that would seem slower than simply testing. My primary objective is **knowing whether something works, and if not, how it has failed, as quickly as possible**.

Comment: Then make your public methods smaller & more granular.

Comment: @slaks The public method is tiny. It adds the minimal network complexity on top of the larger, non-networked private method, which is only ever called from the public method.

Answer (score 1):

Unit-tests are not supposed to tell you which exact line has bug in your code. Unit-tests are only supposed to verify that your public methods adhere to specification. If some method fails to pass test, then you see which part of specification is not satisfied. And it's up to you to understand why. If you have exception, then exception message/stacktrace can tell you source of problem. You also can debug unit-test to understand what went wrong.

If you spend to many time finding which private method has bug, then probably your class is too complex or it does too many things. Consider to extract some functionality to separate class and write unit tests for it.

Comment: Simple example: a small, private function does an integrated job (eg, building a file in a specific format). A larger, public method wraps that in more complex network tasks. A unit test on the private method quickly identifies whether the file built is incorrect, or whether there's a larger issue with networking being broken.

Comment: That sounds exactly like *too many responsibilities* case. Doing network tasks and building files in specific format is very different jobs. Create file builder and write tests for it. Then use file builder in your class which does network job.

Comment: Yes, they're separate jobs - **that's why they're separate methods**. However one is only ever called from the other, which is why it is  private. All you're asking me to do here is expose something unnecessarily and then write tests for it.

Comment: @mikemaccana I explaind how you should find which part of private implementation is failed (*thats was your question*). Then I suggested to extract class, because your current class has many reasons to change (i.e. it violates SRP). It does not matter how many consumers of file generator you will have. Most of classes are not used for code reuse. It's just tool for dealing with complexity of code by aggregating related data and logic together. Logic of file generation worth moving to separate class. I didn't ask you to expose something unnecessarily. I asked you for code refactoring.

Comment: I have specifically explained how the separate methods adhere to SRP. It does matter how many consumers of the file generator there are, because a method/function should not be exposed externally if it will not be used externally. When you say 'create file builder and write tests for it' I assume you mean expose file builder publicly. If you mean something else, please state what.

Comment: @mikemaccana actually generator *will* be used externally. Your class will be external user of file generator, and your class will provide specification to functionality of generator (I assume you are using Python, so I can't help you with class visibility options - with .NET you can set internal visibility for classes which should not be used outside assembly). But even having public file generator is not a problem here.

Comment: It will only be used 'externally' by a single function, and will only only be external because you specifically wanted it to be external. I do see what you're saying: have a separate module that's only loaded in one place, but that's exposing something which has no purpose outside the single module that depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using java/junit the stacktrace show all the methods called and where it breaks.
I think a similar mecanism exists in c# and other modern languages...